# Android Custom Controls with textviews inside them

Tags: android

I am making a Custom control and I want to add **TextViews** inside it. How Can I do that ? 
Any ideas?

The custom controls will be used to display electronic programming guide(EPG). My application is for google tv and will be used for channels listing and playback and EPG, in EPG screen i will show the time intervals and programs in each intervals , I want to use Textviews for Program names and to give them custom fonts and style.

Any kind of help will be appreciated,
Many thanks,[image]

Here is screen shot of my custo control ? to add the texts styles i want to use textviews. I hope its clear now?

Comment: what kind of custom control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to build further upon this example code:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void addTextView(String text) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
        tv.setText(text);
        this.addView(tv);
        this.invalidate(); //I think this is called implicitly, but just in case.
    }
}
```

However, you have to do thing like margins, scrolling, layout and so on yourself, as your context does not give many clues.

EDIT: with the addition of some context, I suggest you use a `TableLayout`. Still, you can build that with the given example code.

Comment: I again edited my question, and yes tablelayout is a good suggestion , i will try it out.